# Local issuer certificate - SSL

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, manjaro

I am running a Linux machine under ManjaroLinux 23.0.1 Uranos with a GNOME desktop.

I have been working with python (current version 3.11.5) and the request library for some years now.
I use it for sending queries to several API's which has recently changed their URL structure.

Since this URL structure change, I am not able to send requests anymore due to the following SSL error:

```
Max retries exceeded with url: /login/connect/token (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)')))
```

It seems that I am missing a root certificate.
The IT department that changed the URL to put everything under the same domain name told me that the root certificate issuer is AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2, Organisation (O) GlobalSign nv-sa.

I am rather unfamiliar with that subject but proceeded to these websites:

- https://support.globalsign.com/ca-certificates/intermediate-certificates/alphassl-intermediate-certificates
- https://support.globalsign.com/ca-certificates/root-certificates/globalsign-root-certificates

I downloaded and "installed" almost all the certificates on these pages following this procedure:

https://gist.github.com/hamburghammer/44fe193db30107924ea9eafe7325e92e

Nothing seems to fix the issue and I am stuck in something I do not really understand.
Any lead on where to start debugging and learning more about the issue would be welcome.

Thank you for your time and patience.

R3s0luti0n